# How to initialize a value in nasm structure segment text

Tags: c, assembly, structure, nasm

How to initialize a value in a structure in NASM without initializing a value in rodata. For example I would like to move a value directly into my structure in my code segment? Thanks to you !

I would like to point out that I am a beginner, so it is possible that I have done something wrong.

I'm sorry, I've just changed the code because I had made a mistake I had forgotten my type I have this error now

my code:

```
BITS 64

global _start


segment .bss
        struc test
                value: resb 256
        endstruc

segment .data
        name db "Bryton", 0

        test_struc:
                istruc test
                        at value, db "Hello world"
                iend

segment .text

_start:
        mov rax, [test_struc.value]
        mov rax, name
        jmp _exit

_exit:
        mov rax, 0x3c
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall
```

Error

```
struct.s:22: error: symbol `test_struc.value' undefined
struct.s:26: error: label `_exit' changed during code generation [-w+error=label-redef-late]
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `mov` instruction?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work on my side. I think I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: I can help you with doing it right, but to understand your problem, I need to see your code and a detailed problem description.

Comment: Yes i have edit my post with the source code

Comment: I'm sorry, I've just changed the code because I had made a mistake I had forgotten my type I have this error now

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the probleme

Solution:

```
BITS 64

global _start


segment .bss
        struc test
                value: resb 256
        endstruc

segment .data
        name db "Bryton", 0

        test_struc:
                istruc test
                        at value, db "Hello world"
                iend

segment .text

_start:
        mov rax, name
        mov [test_struc+value], rax

        mov rax, 0x1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, [test_struc+value]
        mov rdx, 6
        syscall
        jmp _exit

_exit:
        mov rax, 0x3c
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall
```